# Related Products only by Tags, Not by Categories in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, categories

I try to get the opposite of: [Related Products only by categories, not by tags in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698470/related-products-only-by-categories-not-by-tags-in-woocommerce-3)

I would like to show related products based only on product Tags, and Not by categories.

So far I have this in my `function.php` under my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', function( $term_ids, $product_id ){
    return array();
}, 10, 2 );
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In woocommerce version 3.2.x, I have tested first this code to only show related products based on product tags only:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category', '__return_false' );
```

For product tags you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag', '__return_false' );
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* **It works perfectly.**

> **Important:** To see changes, clear transients by going in WooCommerce > Status > tools and in "WooCommerce transients" click on "Clear transients" button.

**Your code works too,** so there is something that is making trouble. It can be a plugin, your theme or some other code made by you.

Comment: See the comment here on Transients. Once I removed them, it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122389/woocommerce-related-products-by-tags-and-categories#comment116919918_61307755